# Vba: case within if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I do not know want i'm doing wrong. 
In  column H there a values like Bank,  Chair Table. 
If in the  column is table then i want to run a case, the case of  column C. In case in  column C is value 10 or 20 this has the be copied to  column F. In case else the row has to get a color. 
Now every r column C with values <> 10, 20 get a message, also if there is in  column  H Chair or other

What is wrong in the code?

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To Worksheets("Read DBF").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
    If Worksheets("Read DBF").Cells(i, "I") = "OLN" Then
      Select Case Worksheets("Read DBF").Cells(i, "C")
          Case 10, 20, 30
              Worksheets("Read DBF").Cells(i, "F") = Worksheets("Read DBF").Cells(i, "C")
          Case Else
              MsgBox "Wrong number"
       End Select
    End If
Next i
Sheet1.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no row H, there is only a column H

Comment: Sorry edit the question, had to be  column

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect that the *10, 20, 30* values may be text masquerading as numbers. `10` is NOT the same thing as `"10"` . Check their default cell alignment. Text is left-aligned and numbers/dates are right-aligned. You can test for both.

Dim i As Long

```
With Worksheets("Read DBF")
    For i = 2 To .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row
        If UCase(.Cells(i, "I").Value) = "OLN" Then
            Select Case LCase(.Cells(i, "H").Value2)
                Case "bank"
                    'do something for 'bank'
                Case "chair"
                    'do something for 'chair'
                Case "table"
                   Select Case .Cells(i, "C").Value2
                       Case 10, 20, 30, "10", "20", "30"
                           .Cells(i, "F") = .Cells(i, "C").Value2
                       Case Else
                           .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 26).Interior.Color = vbRed
                           MsgBox "Wrong number"
                    End Select
                Case Else
                    'not 'bank', 'chair' or 'table'
            End Select
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

I've nested a second [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) into conditions where column H is *'table'*. There are placeholders for *'bank'* and *'chair'*.

I've also added a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) to make your code a little more readable.

Comment: I think he was also asking how to loop through an array of values to test in the first If statement.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner. Yes, my reply may be imcomplete; I'm hoping for some clarification if the OP can get past this point.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped you are right the values where text. Also the color works perfect.